# Search only in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search only in column A.

With apple as an example, this searches the whole sheet.

```vb
Cells.Find(What:=apple, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
  :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
  False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: Range("A:A").find  more info can be found here: https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-use-the-range-find-method/

Answer (score 0):

Implicit `cells` always refers to the active sheets cells.

Be **explicit** regarding the range you want to search within

```vb
Dim rgToSearch As Range
Set rgToSearch = ActiveSheet.Columns("A")

rgToSearch.Find ...
```